# Как в DataGrid WPF добавить строку итогов (footer)?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Подскажите, кто знает, как добавить строку суммы итогов в DataGrid для WPF? Некоторые ресурсы предлагают использовать <DataGrid.FooterTemplate>, где-то просто <DataGrid.Footer>.
Вот тут:
https://www.iditect.com/faq/csharp/how-to-add-a-footer-row-in-a-wpf-datagrid.html
предлагается использовать

К сожалению ни один из этих вариантов не распознается студией.

Использую VS2022, .Net8

Спасибо

Comment: Потому что таких механик нет в WPF, вам нужно изобретать свои "велосипеды", например [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522889/6808809).

Comment: Данный вариант не подходит по той причине, что количество столбцов у меня выходит за пределы окна. Нужна горизонтальная прокрутка. Нужно иметь возможность менять размеры столбцов и их положение. У меня такое решение реализовано, и в силу этих требований конечному пользователю выдается каша

Comment: На киберфоруме некто harmin хвастался, что менял структуру ItemPresenter и у него заработало. Но не показал как он это сделал. Я подумал, что может у кого-то есть решение. Хотя бы близко. Чтобы можно было при необходимости допилить